# Datatype returned varies based on data in table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a table with two column - [security_role_name] and security_role_cd . Datatype for security_role_cd is smallint in Security_Role table.

I have following data selection logic. The datatype returned varies based on the scenario of data:-

1. No data in table
2. One record present in table

**Questions**

1. Why is the datatype varying in these scenarios
2. How to correct it

**Note**: Currently i am using `try..catch` to meet this scenario

CODE

```
    private int GetNextRoleID(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        int? newRoleID = null;
        //string commandText = "SELECT  (MAX(security_role_cd)) AS [NewRoleID] FROM Security_Role ";
        string commandText = "SELECT  TOP 1 security_role_cd AS [NewRoleID] FROM Security_Role ORDER BY security_role_cd DESC";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    //newRoleID = Convert.ToInt32((reader.GetInt16(0)) + 1);

                    try
                    {
                        newRoleID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt16(0)) + 1;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        int result = (reader.GetInt32(0));
                        newRoleID = result + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();

        if (newRoleID == null)
        {
            newRoleID = 1;
        }

        return (Convert.ToInt32(newRoleID));

    }
```

REFERENCE:

1. [How do I get the SqlDbType of a column in a table using ADO.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459572/how-do-i-get-the-sqldbtype-of-a-column-in-a-table-using-ado-net?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at `reader.GetFieldType(0)`. For example:

```
    int i;
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(reader.GetFieldType(0)))
    {
        case TypeCode.Int16: i = reader.GetInt16(0); break;
        case TypeCode.Int32: i = reader.GetInt32(0); break;
        // TODO: any other cases you need to handle
        default: throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

or perhaps simpler:

```
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
```

Comment: Thanks. Is following also worth using?  SqlDbType type = (SqlDbType)(int)reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows[0]["ProviderType"];

Comment: @Lijo that adds a lot of overhead... the reader already knows the types... just ask the reader what the type is, IMO.